# Excel Countifs or SumProduct formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I have collision data in column `F` I have the years from 2004-2015, I have named the range `ATT_YEAR` and In column `G` I have the dates and the range is named `ATT_DATE`. What I am trying to do is to either use `COUNTIFS` or `SUMPRODUCT` to determine the number of collisions by month of the year, if I select the year as say 2013, I want to show the number of collisions by month.
I was trying the following the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(ATT_YEAR,"2013",ATT_DATE,MONTH=1)
```

but not getting very far with one.
Or when I tried using sumproduct formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ATT_YEAR,"2013"),MONTH(ATT_DATE)=1)
```

I would be grateful for any assist on either of these.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the formula wrong:

```
=SUMIFS(COLLISION,ATT_YEAR,2013,ATT_MONTH,1)
```

This will count all collisions in the named-range "COLLISION" only if 2013 is matched in the named-range "ATT_YEAR" and 1 (i.e. January) is matched in the named-range "ATT_MONTH".

#### edit

Needs updating, wrong assumptions.

Comment: Hi CoRrRan, the use of the countifs is like "COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)" whereas in your formula you have the added range COLLISION. Also just have the date not the month. I could create an extra column for the month but when the data is received it does not have the additional column for the month. To keep it as simple as possible I want to work only with data that's been provided rather than creating additional columns.

Comment: You are correct that I am indeed using the wrong formula.  My example uses the SUMIFS, it happened due to poor translation on my part.  I assumed that you have 3 columns: 1 with data, 1 with years and 1 with months.  That is obviously incorrect.  I guess that it would be nice to have a view of your exact data.

Comment: Ho CoRrRan, I have managed to resolve the issue I was having. The Date is in format dd/mm/yyyy from which I needed to extract only the month. I managed to resolve it using SUMPRODUCT in the following way =SUMPRODUCT((ATT_YEAR=$C$2)*(MONTH(ATT_DATE)=1)). In cell C2 I would change the year. I'm still trying it using countifs and will let you know if I succeed.

Comment: Good to hear that you are making progress. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `MONTH`, which is the function you need, inside `COUNTIFS`. Instead, create another column, with the formula `MONTH(B2)`, assuming column `B` has the date values, and use it as a new `ATT_MONTH` range:

```
=COUNTIFS(ATT_YEAR,2004,ATT_MONTH,6)
```